# An error has occurred. Websocket error: undefined in Linkerd Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, devops, linkerd

I have minikube running in AWS EC2 Instance, Meshed the application with linkerd, when i try to monitor the Live Calls throws **An error has occurred. Websocket error: undefined** in the linkerd dashboard.

Note: I have exposed the linkerd dashboard by updating the config args for enforced-host in linkerd viz install

```
> - args:
>         ...
>         - -enforced-host=.*
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my ingress by default doesn't support websockets. Want to get that configured or just use port forwarding. used port forwarding it worked as expected

Refer this https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/discussions/5264

Answer (score 0):

My Ingress Looks like this. Its the ingress described on thier site: https://linkerd.io/2.14/tasks/exposing-dashboard/index.html#nginx
I added the bottom 5 lines to make it work with nginx-ingress. It stopped the warnings for me.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  namespace: linkerd-viz
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: $service_name.$namespace.svc.cluster.local:8084
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Origin "";
      proxy_hide_header l5d-remote-ip;
      proxy_hide_header l5d-server-id;      
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: web-ingress-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: web
    nginx.org/websocket-services: web
```